# OLEDB Error code DB_SEC_E_AUTH_FAILED(0x80040E4D)

Tags: vb.net, oledb

I'm using the following code to pull the command line arguments for my projects load

```
Public Sub CMD()

        Dim sCommandLine() As String
        sCommandLine = Split(Command$, ",")

        If sCommandLine(0) = "" Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        RiskChoose = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Trim(sCommandLine(0))
        RiskCode = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Trim(sCommandLine(1))
        RiskDate = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Trim(sCommandLine(2))
        txtUnitCode.Text = RiskCode.ToString
        TextBox1.Text = RiskChoose
    End Sub
```

This should then populate a textbox with the value of RiskCode and then a subsequent OLEDB query will run and populate some other textboxes

This seems to be working OK and if if add the command lines to the 'Debug' section on VS2012 it picks up the right values and the project opens.

The problem comes when i Build the project and run this through a secondry project which supplies the Command Line parameters. When i click to load the first project from within the second project i get the following error `DB_SEC_E_AUTH_FAILED(0x80040E4D)` and it points to the following line (son.open()) in the below query code.

```
   Public Sub NameQuery()
        Try
            Dim search As String = txtUnitCode.Text
            Dim aClients As String = My.Settings.ClientDBLoc
            Dim lnText As String = String.Empty
            Dim sConnString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source=" & aClients & ""
            Using son As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(sConnString)
                son.Open() '''''''''''''This is the error line
                If txtUnitCode.Text = "" Then Exit Sub
                Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT LongName FROM Units " & "WHERE (Code = ?) AND (UnitIsDead = False)", son)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a1?", search)
                Dim r As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                If Not r.HasRows Then Exit Sub
                Do While r.Read()
                    lnText = lnText & r.GetValue(0)
                Loop
            End Using
            txtUnitName.Text = lnText
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Any idea why this may be??

Thanks

Comment: What is the supposed value of the aClients string? Did you check if you have a valid path to the MDB file?

Comment: It's a path to an access MDB, i've triple checked the path and it's right and it works on a number of other queries that execute in both the programs

Comment: I see, however I would put a MessageBox.Show(aClients) before trying to open the connection. (just in case...)